# How to alter tabs that have wildcard in bartik main menu

Tags: routes

The problem is that I have some menu items with wildcard that I wanna add in main menu tabs, but can't realize how to do it. It can't be solved by `hook_menu` as I undestood. Tried use `preprocess_links__system_main_menu`, `menu_tree__main_menu` but they didn't execute. How correctly do this?

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by page preprocess function. Not sure is this correct way or not.

```
function mobitek_custom_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = ($nid && arg(0) == 'community' && is_numeric($nid)) ? node_load($nid) : FALSE;
  if (!$node) {
    return;
  }
  $main_menu = &$vars['main_menu'];
  $mobitek_menu_items = array(
    'communities',
    'reports',
    'administrators',
    'users',
  );
  // Remove links by this.
  foreach ($main_menu as $key => $menu_array) {
    if (isset($menu_array['identifier']) && in_array($menu_array['href'], $mobitek_menu_items)) {
      unset($main_menu[$key]);
    }
  }

  ....

  foreach ($community_links as $title => $community_link) {
    $new_tab = array(
      'title' => $title,
      'href' => $community_link,
    );
    array_unshift($main_menu, $new_tab);
  }

  // Add link by this. 
  if (arg(0) == 'community' && arg(2) == 'profiles-roles') {
    $on_roles_page = (arg(3) == 'user-roles');
    $profiles_item = menu_get_item('community/' . $nid . '/profiles-roles/user-profiles');
    $vars['tabs']['#primary'][] = array(
      '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
      '#link' => $profiles_item,
      '#active' => !$on_roles_page,
    );
    $roles_item = menu_get_item('community/' . $nid . '/profiles-roles/user-roles');
    $vars['tabs']['#primary'][] = array(
      '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
      '#link' => $roles_item,
      '#active' => $on_roles_page,
    );
  }
}
```